console.log.apply(console, array) vs console.log(array)
I was testing with this code and trying to understand what's really the difference


var array = ['c', 3, {}, "text"]
console.log.apply(console, array); //outputs c 3 {} "text"
console.log(array); //outputs (4) ['c', 3, {…}, "text"]




console.log.apply(console, array), each element of the array is passed as an individual argument to console.log

There's little reason to use apply these days, you can use ... to spread an array: console.log(...array)

To extend console.log (if that's what you're trying to achieve / understand) see: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/j5u8sLw1/
